# Laravel - passing data from master blade to partial doesn't work for all views

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass data from my master blade to the partial depending where it is open. This is part of my master blade:

```
<div id="main-section">
      @section('topBar')
        @include('customer.layouts.partials.top-bar')
      @show

      @section('header')
        @include('customer.layouts.partials.header')
      @show

      @section('carousel')
        @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'drawer'])
      @show
    </div>

    <div id="drawer">
      <div id="item-detail">
      </div>
      <div id="item-detail-carousel">
        @section('carousel')
          @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'itemDetail'])
        @show
      </div>
    </div>
```

So, as you can see I am using `customer.layouts.partials.carousel` in two places.
I am receiving data in my partial like this:

```
      <div class="swiper-container {{ $function }}">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            @foreach($issues as $issue)
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img
                  src="/imagecache/large/{{ $issue->first()->image  }}"
                  onclick="{{ $function }}(
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->id }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->summary ?: '' }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->image ?: '' }}',
                    '{{ $issue->first()->image  }}'
                    )"
                  >
              </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
```

Div `#drawer` is hidden first, has `display:none`, and it is shown on click on an image in the slider in the `main-section`. And then `#drawer` gets slides over the `main-section`. But when I inspect the elements in the chrome I see that both in the `main-section` and in the `drawer` section, data that was passed is `drawer`. The `#drawer` didn't get data `['function' => 'drawer']` as I thought it would. 
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the `@section` directive is meant to work.

For starters, you shouldn't have multiple `@section` directives with the same name (think of it like ids with `HTML` - there should only be one with that name). Also, if your not going to be extending files with `@extend` there isn't much point in using `@section` at all.

If you remove the `@section` directives from around your `@include('...')` then they should work fine.

Hope this helps!